# How do I fully uninstall/erradicate powerline?

Tags: package, emacs24.4, powerline

I'm running `GNU Emacs 24.4.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0, NS apple-appkit-1265.21)
 of 2014-10-20 on builder10-9.porkrind.org`, the one available form gnuemacsformacosx.com. After upgrading, my modeline was mostly blank, and it seemed that this error was due to something involving `powerline`. In any case, I decided to switch to `smart-mode-line`. So I installed the latter package and have attempted to delete `powerline` by

1. deleting it from the package list using `d`, `x`
2. deleting all occurrences of expressions containing 'powerline' in my `.emacs`

However, I am still receiving the following error in my messages when I launch Emacs:

```
Eager macro-expansion failure: (error "Autoloading failed to define function defpowerline")
Error: (file-error "Cannot open load file" "no such file or directory" "powerline")
```

I cannot figure out how to track down the cause of this error. I'm most grateful for any help!

Comment: Your approach should have worked. Are you absolutely certain you don't have a mention of `defpowerline` somewhere?

Comment: Are maybe references in your custom.el? Do you have a .emacs.d directory? Search with ag or ack or grep in all relevant files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> deleting it from the package list using d, x

Normally, it should have worked nice. What about reinstall the powerline package by first deleting it in elpa folder and restart emacs?

Also, isn't there a byte compiled file loaded somewhere? You will probably need to recompile it after removing powerline.

I've just found this [github issue](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/issues/33#issuecomment-60463015). Not really the same environment, but I think it could help.